# Can we code XBee more than once?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano, xbee

How many times we can rewrite code in
 XBEE, can we write code more than one or once a code is written it cannot be overwritten

Comment: `code in XBEE` ... it is unclear what you are referring to

Comment: @jsotola a friend of mine said you can only burn program once in Xbee and then you can never change it

Comment: He said Xbee are like old cd only one burn is allowed